# Stability of weak solutions to quasilinear parabolic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, p-laplace

Consider the quasilinear operator $A(x,t,\nabla u)$ satisfying $$A(x,t,\nabla u).\nabla u \geq C_0 |\nabla u|^p$$ and $$|A(x,t,\nabla u)| \leq C_1 |\nabla u|^{p-1}$$ where $1<p<\infty$. Note that there is no assumption made regarding $<A(x,t,\zeta)-A(x,t,\eta).\zeta-\eta>$, in particular, there is no comparison principle. Moreover, $A(x,t,\nabla u)$ is just measurable function.

Suppose $u \in C^0(0,T; L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^p(0,T; W^{1,p}(\Omega))$ is a local weak solution of $$u_t - \text{div}A(x,t,\nabla u)=0.$$

My question is the following: I need to find a sequence of nonlinearities $A_{\epsilon}(x,t,\zeta)$ satisfying the same structure conditions as $A(x,t,\zeta)$, but having the following properties:

1) $A_{\epsilon}$ is smooth.

2) Let $u_{\epsilon}$ be the unique weak solution of 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
(u_{\epsilon})_t - \text{div} A_{\epsilon}(x,t,\nabla u_{\epsilon}) = 0\quad  \text{on} \quad Q\\
u_{\epsilon} = u \quad \text{on} \quad \partial_p Q
\end{array}
$$
where $Q$ is a fixed cylinder and $\partial_p Q$ denotes the parabolic boundary of $Q$. Then $u_{\epsilon}$ converges to $u$ locally in $Q$.

Basically, how do I get a local smooth approximation to weak solutions of quasilinear parabolic equations?